# How to assign TextAssets to a scene gameobject via editor script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor, unity-editor

I have a scene with levels. This scene has 1.000 levels. Its level has a TextAsset. I would like to run an EditorScript and assign those TextAssets via script and not by Dragging and dropping 1.000 TextAssets to the scene. Then save the scene automatically.

```c#
Scene mainScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("Main");
GameObject[] gameObjects = mainScene.GetRootGameObjects();
GameManager gameManager = gameObjects[0].GetComponent<GameManager>();
List<LanguageCategory> languageCategories = new List<LanguageCategory>();
LanguageCategoryPackInfo l1 = new LanguageCategoryPackInfo();
l1.displayName = "t1";
LanguageCategoryPackInfo l2 = new LanguageCategoryPackInfo();
l2.displayName = "t2";
languageCategories.Add(l1);
languageCategories.Add(l2);
gameManager.LanguageCategoryPackInfos = languageCategories;
//do the same assignment again, but with no luck
mainScene.GetRootGameObjects()[0].GetComponent<GameManager>().LanguageCategoryPackInfos = languageCategories;
EditorSceneManager.SaveScene(mainScene);
```

After running the above code the scene doesn't seems to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with directly making some changes in the component doesn't mark it as *dirty* and thus changes are not saved! (see also explenation in [`SerializedObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.html) and solution below.)

You can do this manually using [`EditorUtility.SetDirty`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html). As noted there you should always combine it with first also calling [`Undo.RecordObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Undo.RecordObject.html).

If you don't care about the Undo/Redo functionality you can also simply use [`EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty.html)

```c#
Scene mainScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("Main");
GameObject[] gameObjects = mainScene.GetRootGameObjects();
GameManager gameManager = gameObjects[0].GetComponent<GameManager>();

List<LanguageCategory> languageCategories = new List<LanguageCategory>();

LanguageCategoryPackInfo l1 = new LanguageCategoryPackInfo();
l1.displayName = "t1";
LanguageCategoryPackInfo l2 = new LanguageCategoryPackInfo();
l2.displayName = "t2";
languageCategories.Add(l1);
languageCategories.Add(l2);

// record an undo point
Undo.RecordObject(gameManager, "languages added");
gameManager.LanguageCategoryPackInfos = languageCategories;
// mark the object dirty so it will be saved
EditorUtility.SetDirty(gameManager);

// or simply directly
EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty();
EditorSceneManager.SaveScene(mainScene);
```

---

As alternative though it is more complex it is always recommended to instead go through the [`SerializedObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.html) and [`SerializedProperty`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html)s which handles all the marking *dirty* and undo/redo functionalities for you automatically.

```c#
Scene mainScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("Main");
GameObject[] gameObjects = mainScene.GetRootGameObjects();
GameManager gameManager = gameObjects[0].GetComponent<GameManager>();

SerializedObject serializedObject = new SerializedObject(gameManager);

SerializedProperty languageCategories = serializedObject.FindProperty("LanguageCategoryPackInfos");

// load the current real values into the serializedObject
serializedObject.Update();

languageCategories.arraySize = 2;

SerializedProperty l1 = languageCategories.GetArrayElementAtIndex(0);
l1.FindPropertyRelative("displayName").stringValue = "t1";
SerializedProperty l2 = languageCategories.GetArrayElementAtIndex(1);
l2.FindPropertyRelative("displayName").stringValue= "t2";

// writes the changes bakc to the actual properties and marks them as dirty etc
serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();

EditorSceneManager.SaveScene(mainScene);
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warrenty, but I hope the idea gets clear*